# Shell script - Find matching RewriteRule from replace.txt and remove it from .htaccess, Regex?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, .htaccess

I'm having trouble removing lines of RewriteRules from a large .htaccess file. I have a shell script that loops through each line in the .htaccess file to try and find a matching line in a replace.txt file. If the line exists, then remove it from the .htaccess file.

The problem I'm having it when I run the file, I don't believe I have the right regex in the sed command, and it's not ignoring the characters in the line containing the RewriteRule. I've tried several others with no luck.

I copied my .htaccess to test.txt, and I'm using that as if it was the .htaccess for testing.

```
real_htaccess_file=$(cat $file_path/.htaccess)
test_htaccess_file=$(cat $file_path/test.txt)
replace_rules_file=$(cat $file_path/replace.txt)

# loop through each line in test_htaccess_file
while read -r line; do
    # if line contains RewriteRule
    if [[ $line == *"RewriteRule"* ]]; then
        # loop through each line in replace_rules_file
        while read -r replace_line; do
            # if line in test_htaccess_file matches line in replace_rules_file
            if [[ $line == $replace_line ]]; then
                  # log the line
                  echo -e 'Found RewriteRule: '$line

                  # Remove the line from test_htaccess_file
                  sed -i "/$line/d" $file_path/test.txt
                
            fi
        done < $file_path/replace.txt
    fi
done < $file_path/test.txt
```

[image: Output]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `"/$line/d"` is failing when there are `/`s in the `line` variable. It is not safe to use `sed` here. If you post sample input files with expected output then we can try to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, I think you'd be better off using `grep -f`. `grep -f` takes a file with regular expressions, whereas `sed -f` takes a file with `sed` commands.

```
$ cat original.txt
apple
arrow
banana
boomerang
carrot
crow
$ cat remove-these.txt
^ap.*e$
^[a-z]a[lmn]an[abc]$
^[^A-Z]arrot$
$ grep -v -f remove-these.txt original.txt
arrow
boomerang
crow
```

However, without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the source files and the expected output, it's difficult to know if this would work for you.